# How to access Kivy Properties from within its "self" on __init__()

Tags: python, android-recyclerview, kivy

How can I access a [Kivy Property](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html) within a widget's own `__init__()` function?

I wrote a custom [widget in Kivy](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html). I need to display several thousand instances of this widget object in a [Grid](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html) on a kivy [screen](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.modules.screen.html). Doing so crashes the system, so I'm wrapping the GridLayout in a [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html). Doing so makes it render immediately and without any lag. Great!

Previously, I had positional arguments passed to my custom widget's `__init__()` function, which I used to setup a few instance fields that would be used to determine what would appear (and how) in the widget. Unfortunaetly, RecycleView has forced me to replace the positional arguments with Kivy Properties. And I can't seem to access the values of those properties within the object's `__init__()` function.

For simplicity, let's consider this minimal example of the issue, taken from [this question](https://groups.google.com/g/kivy-users/c/4_xaX7xtL_s) on the Kivy Mailing list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty

kv = '''
<TwoButtons>:
# This class is used as the viewclass in the RecycleView
# The means this widget will be instanced to view one element of data from the data list.
# The RecycleView data list is a list of dictionaries.  The keys in the dictionary specify the 
# attributes of the widget.
    Button:
        text: root.left_text
        on_release: print(f'Button {self.text} pressed') 
    Button:
        text: root.right_text
        on_release: print(f'Button {self.text} pressed') 

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 48
        text: 'Add widget to RV list'
        on_release: rv.add()

    RV:                          # A Reycleview
        id: rv
        viewclass: 'TwoButtons'  # The view class is TwoButtons, defined above.
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        bar_width: 10
        RecycleBoxLayout:        
            # This layout is used to hold the Recycle widgets
            default_size: None, dp(48)   # This sets the height of the BoxLayout that holds a TwoButtons instance.


            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None

            height: self.minimum_height   # To scroll you need to set the layout height.
            orientation: 'vertical'
'''


class TwoButtons(BoxLayout):  # The viewclass definitions, and property definitions.
    left_text = StringProperty()
    right_text = StringProperty()

    print( "TwoButtons top" )

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print( "self.left_text:|" +str(self.left_text)+ "|" )
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print( "self.left_text:|" +str(self.left_text)+ "|" )

class RV(RecycleView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'left_text': f'Left {i}', 'right_text': f'Right {i}'} for i in range(2)]

    
    def add(self):
        l = len(self.data)
        self.data.extend(
         [{'left_text': f'Added Left {i}', 'right_text': f'Added Right {i}'} for i in range(l, l + 1)]
        )

class RVTwoApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

RVTwoApp().run()
```

In the above code segment, the custom widget that we're using `RecycleView` to instantiate many instances-of is called `TwoButtons`.

| [image: Screenshot of a CLI terminal showing the execution of the above code and a GUI window with an array of button widgets displayed] |
| --- |
| The buttons in the GUI appear with the text `Left 0` and `Left 1`, as desired -- but attempting to access their values from within `__init__()` results in the empty string (`self.left_text:||`) |

The `TwoButtons` class has two Kivy Properties:

1. StringProperty `left_text` and
2. StringProperty `right_text`

If you execute the app, you can clearly see that `RecycleView` is able to pass the data into the `TwoButtons` instances' Properties, as the text appears in the buttons as-expected.

**The problem is that the value of the `left_text` Property is the empty string inside `__init__()`**

Consider the following execution of the above program:

```
user@buskill:~/tmp/rv$ python3 rv.py 
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/user/.kivy/logs/kivy_24-03-17_23.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
...
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
self.left_text:||
self.left_text:||
self.left_text:||
self.left_text:||
```

As you can see, the `print()` statements inside the `__init__()` function of `TwoButtons` returns an empty string for `left_text` (even though the actual `left_text` in the buttons in the GUI appear as `Left 0` and `Left 1`, as desired).

Moreover, if you click the `Add widget to RV list` button to add a third row of buttons with `Added Left 2` and `Added Right 2` text, then the following new lines are `print()`ed again.

```
self.left_text:||
self.left_text:||
```

How can I actually access a given object's Properties' values from within the object's `__init__()` function?

Answer (score 0):

#### tl;dr

You can access the Kivy Property from within its own instance using the `bind()` function or [the built-in `on_<property_name>()` function](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-on-propname).

```
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
                super().__init__(**kwargs)

        def on_left_text( self, instance, value ):
                print( "self.left_text:|" +str(self.left_text)+ "|" )
```

#### on_<propname>()

I don't know how Kivy instantiates its Properties objects of widgets, but you're right that the value cannot be accessed from within `__init__()`.

But, if you can stand to do your setup a few seconds later, you can just do it after each Property has been set using [the `on_<property_name>()` function](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-on-propname) -- which will get called whenever the `<property_name>` Property's value changes.

- https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-on-propname

From the documnetation:

> **Observe using ‘on_<propname>’**
>
> If you defined the class yourself, you can use the ‘on_’ callback:
>
> ```
> class MyClass(EventDispatcher):
>     a = NumericProperty(1)
>
>     def on_a(self, instance, value):
>         print('My property a changed to', value)
> ```

#### The code

I've updated the program from OP with this change as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty

kv = '''
<TwoButtons>:
# This class is used as the viewclass in the RecycleView
# The means this widget will be instanced to view one element of data from the data list.
# The RecycleView data list is a list of dictionaries.  The keys in the dictionary specify the 
# attributes of the widget.
    Button:
        text: root.left_text
        on_release: print(f'Button {self.text} pressed') 
    Button:
        text: root.right_text
        on_release: print(f'Button {self.text} pressed') 

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 48
        text: 'Add widget to RV list'
        on_release: rv.add()

    RV:                       # A Reycleview
        id: rv
        viewclass: 'TwoButtons'  # The view class is TwoButtons, defined above.
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        bar_width: 10
        RecycleBoxLayout:       
            # This layout is used to hold the Recycle widgets
            default_size: None, dp(48)   # This sets the height of the BoxLayout that holds a TwoButtons instance.


            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None

            height: self.minimum_height   # To scroll you need to set the layout height.
            orientation: 'vertical'
'''


class TwoButtons(BoxLayout):  # The viewclass definitions, and property definitions.
    left_text = StringProperty()
    right_text = StringProperty()

    print( "TwoButtons top" )

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_left_text( self, instance, value ):
        print( "self.left_text:|" +str(self.left_text)+ "|" )

class RV(RecycleView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'left_text': f'Left {i}', 'right_text': f'Right {i}'} for i in range(2)]

    
    def add(self):
        l = len(self.data)
        self.data.extend(
         [{'left_text': f'Added Left {i}', 'right_text': f'Added Right {i}'} for i in range(l, l + 1)]
        )

class RVTwoApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

RVTwoApp().run()
```

#### Execution Example

An example execution of the above program correctly outputs the `left_text` values

```
user@buskill:~/tmp/rv$ python3 rv2.py 
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/user/.kivy/logs/kivy_24-03-17_27.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
...
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
self.left_text:|Left 0|
self.left_text:|Left 1|
self.left_text:|Left 0|
self.left_text:|Left 1|
```